# Pose mode question - cannot rotate or scale generated rig controls in viewport - only works in - item - transform panel

Tags: rigify, pose-mode

I'm having a strange issue that keeps popping up.
I am only able to scale or rotate controls on generated *Rigify* rig from the item - transform menu. I am unable to rotate or scale any of the controls directly in the viewport (transform works fine). This is true for all controls on the rig...

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you so much.
Sincerely,
Jack

[image: screenshot]

Comment: here is a link to blender file. thank you for all help!

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/i0tdbr0m5nrbrz5/bignoserig1.blend?dl=0

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.

Comment: Thank @RickT will do that next time

Answer (score 2):

You have (probably unintentionally) enabled the *Affect Only Locations* option. Just uncheck the option and you can use the gizmos again.

The option is hidden in the *Pose Options* dropdown menu, located in the header of the viewport ...

[image: screenshot affect only location]

... and in the first tab of the *Properties* panel which is called *Active Tool and Workspace settings* and has a "screwdriver and wrench" icon:

[image: active tool settings - affect only location]

Comment: WOW solved! that was it my king!!!!!!  This is my first time ever posting on a forum so surreal. Thank you again!